# ListView DrawSubItem Event

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView control in my windows form. I am adding images to ListView subItems using DrawSubItem event. It seems normal when I populate my ListView. But problem is every time I click ListView, DrawSubItem event fires. Therefore, all images and texts are loading every click and I can't select any item on my ListView. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why you are adding images in DrawSubItem event? Can you add the images before? DrawSubItem is an event to customize the appearance of subitems, it's used to draw the subitems, but you shouldn't modify (add/remove) items/subitems/images in this event.

Comment: I am getting image urls from web service. And I am using e.Graphics.DrawImage method (e is an event handler method parameter which is an instance of DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs). Because I want to customize the appereance of images.

Comment: From your question it seems that you're populating the ListView images in the DrawSubItem event. Are you getting the images (from the web service) in the event or in your form constructor? It looks like you are adding the images inside the DrawSubItem handler (when you shouldn't do that).

Answer (score 0):

I have designed [Better ThumbnailBrowser](http://www.componentowl.com/better-thumbnail-browser) component that solves background loading of images and thread synchronization for you, so that you don't have to set images in draw events.

You can also try [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express), which is free for any kind if usage.

Unlike regular .NET ListView, you can set images of arbitrary sizes in the items.